# Proving that $(x^2 + 2)^n + 5(x^{2n-1} + 10x^2 + 5)$ is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Show that for all positive integers $n,$ $$(x^2 + 2)^n + 5(x^{2n-1} + 10x^2 + 5)$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x].$

---

I think [Schonemann's criterion](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Schonemann%27s_criterion) finishes off the problem but I'm not sure how to show that $x^2 + 2 \pmod{5}$  doesn't divide $x^{2n-1} + 10x^2 + 5.$

Comment: I'm referencing https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Schonemann%27s_criterion.

Comment: Oh, that criterion seems to finish off the problem indeed. What are you stuck at?

Comment: I don't know how to show that $x^2 + 2$ modulo 5 doesn't divide $x^{2n-1} + 10x^2 + 5$ modulo $5.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the criterion you mention, the only thing left to show is that $x^2 + 2$ does not divide $x^{2n - 1} + 10x^2 + 5$ over the field $\Bbb F_5$. (This is just a fancy way of saying "modulo $5$".)

However, note that modulo $5$, we have $$x^{2n - 1} + 10x^2 + 5 \equiv x^{2n - 1}.$$

Since $\Bbb F_5[x]$ is a UFD, we can conclude directly that $x^2 + 2$ does not divide $x^{2n - 1}$ and this finishes the job.